# Filter out non duplicate value from array of array in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
const array = [
  [
    'USA',
    'Apple',
    'New York',
    'Military'
  ],
  [
    'INDIA',
    'Mango',
    'New delhi',
    'AirCraft'
   ],
  [
    'United Kingdom',
    'Apple',
    'London',
    'Fighter'
]
] 

        var outputArray = []; 
        
        var count = 0; 
        
        var start = false; 
        
        for (j = 0; j < array.length; j++) { 
            for (k = 0; k < outputArray.length; k++) { 
                if ( array[j][1] == outputArray[k][1] ) { 
                    start = true; 
                } 
            } 
            count++; 
            if (count == 0 && start == false) { 
                outputArray.push(array[j][1]); 
            } 
            start = false; 
            count = 0; 
        } 
        document.write(outputArray);
```

I am trying to filter out non duplicate from array of array but didn't get success

I was expecting only

[
'INDIA',
'Mango',
'New delhi',
'AirCraft'
],

It should only check with index of 1 if duplicate matches found just discard this from array and print rest.

Comment: why were you expecting only the second array? because the 1st and 3rd have one element in common?

Comment: Yes that's correct both have Apple in the index of 1

Answer (score 1):

Say you define a `toLookup` function as follows:

```
const toLookup = (arr, keySelector) => arr.reduce((map, curr)=>{
  const key=keySelector(curr);
  const a = map.has(key) ? map.get(key) : [];
  a.push(curr);
  map.set(key, a);
  return map;
}, new Map())
```

which generates a Map where values are grouped by the selected key.

Now all we have to do is find values in this map that have a length of precisely 1:

```
const array = [
  ["USA", "Apple", "New York", "Military"],
  ["INDIA", "Mango", "New delhi", "AirCraft"],
  ["United Kingdom", "Apple", "London", "Fighter"]
];

const lookup = toLookup(array, v => v[1])

const uniques = [...lookup.values()].filter(v => v.length === 1)

console.log(uniques)
```

Comment: Thanks for support, Its working well, can you do me a favour is it possible duplicate row could push to new array ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.flat` and a helper object to count the occurrences and then filter the array where the count is greater than 1.

```js
let array = [
  [
    'USA',
    'Apple',
    'New York',
    'Military'
  ],
  [
    'INDIA',
    'Mango',
    'New delhi',
    'AirCraft'
  ],
  [
    'United Kingdom',
    'Apple',
    'London',
    'Fighter'
  ]
];
const counter = {}

array.flat().forEach(i => counter[i] ? counter[i]++ : counter[i] = 1);

const dupes =Object.entries(counter)
  .filter(([k, v]) => v > 1)
  .map(([k,v])=> k);
  
array = array.filter(i => !dupes.some(d=> i.includes(d)));

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Array.prototype.some()`, you can check if the duplicated values are existed or not.

And using `Array.prototype.findIndex`, you can find the existed index.

Finally, using `Array.prototype.reduce`, you can get the result.

```js
const array = [
  [
    'USA',
    'Apple',
    'New York',
    'Military'
  ],
  [
    'INDIA',
    'Mango',
    'New delhi',
    'AirCraft'
  ],
  [
    'United Kingdom',
    'Apple',
    'London',
    'Fighter'
  ]
];

const result = array.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const existed = acc.findIndex((item) => item.some((subItem) => cur.includes(subItem)));
  if (existed >= 0) {
    acc.splice(existed, 1);
  } else {
    acc.push(cur);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: only return one value even if I change Apple to potato it should return all three as nothing match with any fruit array index

Comment: Its not working properly if I changed the values and put difference one i.e 

const array = [
  [
    'tester',
    'this one indexx',
    '3',
    '4'
  ],
  [
    'Test2',
    'this is second indexx',
    '2',
    '5'
  ],
  [
    'Test3',
    'this is third indexx',
    '1',
    '5'
  ]
];

this should return all array

Comment: For that example, it should return the first item only because second and third contains `5`. And mine works as expected.